# make a scene three.js move

Tags: javascript, three.js

i am working on an the application to optimize packs in a truck.
i use three.js to show the 3D results.

below is the code i use.

i want to make it a moving scene , i want the boxes to show one by one move towards there position inside the truck

[curent 3D result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGAdg.png)

i don't know how to do that, any idea please ?

```
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        init();
        //render(); // remove when using next line for animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xcccccc );
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 400, 200, 0 );
            // controls
            controls = new THREE.MapControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // call this only in static scenes (i.e., if there is no animation loop)
            controls.enableDamping = true; // an animation loop is required when either damping or auto-rotation are enabled
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
            controls.minDistance = 1;
            controls.maxDistance = 50;
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
            // world
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            geometry.translate( 0, 0.5, 0 );
            

            console.log("this is the list we get " , result ) ;
            for (Element in result)
            {

                if( result[Element].Object === "Box" || result[Element].Object === "BigBox"  )
                {
                    
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { opacity: 0.25 , color: getRandomColor() , transparent: false } );
                    var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { opacity: 0.25 , color: getRandomColor() , transparent: true } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                    if(result[Element].Object === "BigBox")
                    {
                        mesh.opacity = 0.01
                        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material2 );
                    }
                    mesh.opacity = 0.75
                     mesh.position.x = result[Element].CenterPoint.X ;
                     mesh.position.y = result[Element].CenterPoint.Y;
                     mesh.position.z = result[Element].CenterPoint.Z;
                     mesh.scale.x = result[Element].Dimentions.X;
                     mesh.scale.y = result[Element].Dimentions.Y;
                     mesh.scale.z = result[Element].Dimentions.Z;
                    mesh.updateMatrix();
                    mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                    scene.add( mesh );
                }
            }  
            // lights
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
            light.position.set( - 1, - 1, - 1 );
            scene.add( light );
            var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light );
            //
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update(); // only required if controls.enableDamping = true, or if controls.autoRotate = true
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
        var link = document.createElement( 'a' );
        link.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild( link ); // Firefox workaround, see #6594
        function save( blob, filename ) {
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
            link.download = filename;
            link.click();
            // URL.revokeObjectURL( url ); breaks Firefox...
        }
        function saveString( text, filename ) {
            save( new Blob( [ text ], { type: 'text/plain' } ), filename );
        }
        function saveArrayBuffer( buffer, filename ) {
            save( new Blob( [ buffer ], { type: 'application/octet-stream' } ), filename );
        }
```

Comment: the simplest suggestion would be to move your elements for loop from the init() to the animate() and render() every time you add a mesh to the scene.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you well, you have two tasks to do:

1. Move the camera
2. Show the boxes one by one

**MOVE THE CAMERA**

Create a global variable:

```
let previousTime = performance.now();
```

Then create an update() function and call it in your animate() function:

```
function update() {
   const time = performance.now();
   const deltaTime = time - previousTime; // this variable tells us, how much time has passed since the last frame (the last call of update() function)
   previousTime = time;

   moveCamera(deltaTime);
}
```

And the moveCamera() function:

```
function moveCamera(deltaTime) {
    // you have to set this variable by your preferences
    const SPEED = 10; 

    // This is the vector that determines the direction in which your camera moves. 
    // In this case the camera will move only along the X axis. 
    // Set it by your preferences depending on which way you want the camera to move.
    const MoveCameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0); 

    // You have to multiply it by SPEED and by deltaTime
    // Multiplying by deltaTime is to make the movement speed independent of the number of FPS
    MoveCameraDirection.multiplyScalar( SPEED * deltaTime );

    camera.position.add(MoveCameraDirection);
}
```

Camera movement is done.

**SHOW THE BOXES ONE BY ONE**

You need to have a handler to your boxes. So create a variable **boxes** and place your objects there:

```
var camera, controls, scene, renderer, boxes = [];
...
// before scene.add( mesh );
mesh.visible = false ; // set all boxes invisible at the begin
boxes.push(mesh);
```

Now, in your update() function, under moveCamera(deltaTime) you can call showBoxes().
The question is: when to show the boxes? Let's say we want to show the boxes, when the camera passes them.
Let's create this function:

```
function showBoxes() {
   // I don't know which direction is your camera moving, so let's assume it's moving along the X axis (like in previos function). You can use any other axis as well.
   // We want to show only the boxes that have **box.position.x < camera.position.x** and are not currenly displayed
   const boxesToShow = boxes.filter( box => !box.visible && box.position.x < camera.position.x);
   for( let i=0 ; i < boxesToShow.length ; i++ ) {
      // we can do it just like this:
      // boxesToShow[i].visible = true;
      // but we don't want them to show all at once, so let's use a timer and display them one by one in 1 second intervals
      setTimeout( () => boxesToShow[i].visible=true, i * 1000 );
   }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to give me an answer , i am new to 3D javaScript this help me so much.
just one thing , i don't want to move the camera while adding boxes, i want to let control to the user to change the view .

instead i want boxes to appear in a given position,  and then move to the mosition where they are supposed to be .

for example if a have two boxes of dimensions (1,1,1) the first one in supposed to be at the position ( x= 0 , y = 0 , z = 0 ) and the second ( x = 0.5 , y = 0 , z= 0 ) .

i want to first to show at the ( 10,10,10) for example ,

Comment: and move to the intended position ( x= 0 , y = 0 , z = 0 )  , and than the second box appear at also at ( 10,10,10 ) and move little by little to  ( x = 0.5 , y = 0 , z= 0 ).